# How to print non-numeric values

Tags: sas

I'm working with data from a survey that allowed study participants to type in numeric responses, rather than providing them with a drop-down menu for them to select a numeric responses. As a result, I have responses that include characters (e.g. "9-12" or "7?"). I would like to identify the observations that have characters in them.

Thanks in advance!

The code I have in mind is getting me stuck on the WHERE statement.

PROC PRINT DATA=library.survey;
VAR record_id;
WHERE var1 ......
RUN;

Is there something I can write that's essentially telling SAS to print the record IDs where var1 doesn't equal a numeric value?

Answer (score 1):

Just print the non-missing values that INPUT() cannot convert to a number. If they might have stuck in leading blanks then use the LEFT() function to remove them.  Also watch out for values that are too long to be valid numbers.

```
where not missing(var1) 
  and (lengthn(left(var1)) <= 32 and missing(input(left(var1),?32.)))
```

Or use the COMMA informat instead of the normal informat and values with commas and/or dollar signs will also be treated as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by regular expressions using `prxmatch`.

```
proc print data=survey;
where prxmatch("/\D/",compress(var1));
run;
```

This will match any non digit characters. We use compress around `var1` to remove any whitespace.

Comment: That would only work for integer values.  Also wouldn't detect strings of digits that are too long to be represented by an 8 byte floating point number.

Comment: @Tom I would think that it's a benefit that negative numbers and decimals are identified as potential issues. I don't know who the audience of the survey is, but a 32 digit number seems unlikely.